# Remove backslashes from string so as to use that string in a FOR loop (for batch doc conversion)

Tags: windows, string, variables, cmd

I'm trying to batch convert old word docs to docx using LibreOffice (the only program I can find that will still display the files with correct formatting) using the Windows 7 command line (via a batch file).  I need to mirror the old folder/directory structure for all those files in creating the new ones.  I have this almost working with the following:

```
for /R d:\docs %%I in (*) do (
soffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" --outdir "d:\docsfinal%%~pI" "%%I"
)
```

Here's the problem:

LibreOffice `--outdir` (output directory) will not accept a path that includes a trailing backslash.  And that's exactly what `%%~pI` spits out-- the path of that variable *with* a trailing backslash. So I need to get rid of that backslash before inserting it in `--outdir`.

So after much googling and searching of stack exchange, I came up with this franken-code (I'm not a programmer, truthfully):

```
for /R d:\docs %%I in (*) do (
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set J=%%~pI
set K=%J:~0,-1%
soffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" --outdir "d:\docsfinal%K%" "%%I"
ENDLOCAL
)
```

But, when I run this the `J` variable does not get reset to the new value (from the new path that should be supplied through `%%~pI`) each time the loop loops. So all my files end up in one directory. It's like it sets `J` once and then always uses that value, no matter what it's set to each time through.

I'd be grateful for any pointers on what I'm doing wrong (other than being a non-programmer yet dabbling with the command prompt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion if you are going to define and expand a variable within a FOR loop. You properly enabled delayed expansion, but you need to use `set K=!J:~0,-1!` instead of `set K=%J:~0,-1%`. Also use `"d:\docsfinal!K!"`.

But there is a better (simpler) way that avoids delayed expansion :-)

```
for /R d:\docs %%I in (*) do for /f "eol=: delims=" %%J in ("%%I\..") do (
  soffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" --outdir "d:\docsfinal%%~pnxJ" "%%I"
)
```

Or even better yet, I think the following will work (simply append a dot to the path). But I haven't tested this.

```
for /R d:\docs %%I in (*) do (
  soffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" --outdir "d:\docsfinal%%~pI." "%%I"
)
```

Comment: The last (simplest option) does work!  Thank you!  I don't understand why, but using ! did not work.  The exclamation points were passed through literally to the output so that I got a new directory called docsfinal!K!